# Filtering walls by Base Constraint: The filter value is not valid for the field and filter type

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I'm having difficulty trying to filter out walls by the **WALL_BASE_CONSTRAINT**. This is the code I currently have. The Build is successful but when I execute the plugin. I come up with the exception: The filter value is not valid for the field and filter type.
Parameter name: filter

I have successfully tried this code on other BuiltInParameters like Material_Name, ALL_MODEL_DESCRIPTION.

```
private static void AddFilterToSchedule(Document doc, ViewSchedule 
schedule)
 {
        string value = "Foundation";

        using (Transaction transaction = new Transaction(schedule.Document, "Filter Material TakeOff"))
        {
            transaction.Start();

            ScheduleDefinition definition = schedule.Definition;
            ScheduleField scheduleField = FindField(schedule, BuiltInParameter.WALL_BASE_CONSTRAINT);

            ScheduleFilter filter = new ScheduleFilter(scheduleField.FieldId, ScheduleFilterType.NotEqual, value);
            definition.AddFilter(filter);

            transaction.Commit();
        }

    }

public static ScheduleField FindField(ViewSchedule schedule, 
BuiltInParameter paramEnum)
    {
        ScheduleDefinition definition = schedule.Definition;
        ScheduleField foundField = null;
        ElementId paramId = new ElementId(paramEnum);

        foreach (ScheduleFieldId fieldId in definition.GetFieldOrder())
        {
            foundField = definition.GetField(fieldId);
            if (foundField.ParameterId == paramId)
            {
                return foundField;
            }
        }
        return foundField;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does `FindField` come from and what does it do?

Have you looked at the [`ScheduleCreation` Revit SDK sample](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/04/developer-center-and-sdk-update.html#22)?

Comment: Hey Jeremy, thanks for your reply. I have edited the code. Now you can check the "FindField" method. 
I have successfully created the schedule. I am facing issue on applying filter on Wall_Base_Constraint.

Comment: Have you looked at the ScheduleCreation Revit SDK sample?

Comment: Yes, I did. That code is working fine for other parameters but not for Wall_Base_Constraint. Can't figure out why I am getting this error.

Comment: You know that the wall base constraint is an `ElemenId`?

Comment: As far as I know, wall base constraint is `BuiltInParameter` and we filter it by getting its `ElementId`. I am passing 'value' as a string.
Do I have to use `ScheduleFilter Constructor (ScheduleFieldId, ScheduleFilterType, ElementId)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to make sure that "Include Elements in Links" is set to False, or otherwise not checked in your created schedule.

This results in not being able to filter by Base Constraint.